# ffmpeg taking lot of data for ip cams streaming

Tags: ffmpeg, rtsp

I have an ip cam which is connected to a cellular router.

rtsp://admin:admin1234@172.xxx.xx.xxx:82/cam/realmonitor?channel=1&subtype=1

This is the rtsp link of my ip cam. When i insert this link inside VLC it gives me sub stream one (one with the less quality). Now when i compare the output of vlc to my cameras substream 1 it looks the same.  Thats what i want. But when i put this link inside ffmpeg it gives me a much better quality video and it does not look like my sub stream 1 from the camera, but im using the same link. Because of this the router that my ip cam is connected is consuming a lot of data. Any help is appreciated.

ffmpeg code

```
ffmpeg -rtsp_transport tcp -v verbose  -i rtsp://admin:admin1234@172.xxx.xx.xxx:82/cam/realmonitor?channel=1&subtype=1    -f hls    -hls_flags delete_segments    -hls_time 5  -segment_time 5 -hls_list_size 5 C:\Apache24\htdocs\ipcam\video_1\stream.m3u8
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this is silly, but it may help anyone who has trouble. For the /live link, you can write just as it is. But for the real monitor link you need to add the rstp link inside  " ".

For example

ffmpeg -rtsp_transport tcp -v verbose  -i "rtsp://admin:admin1234@172.xxx.xx.xxx:82/cam/realmonitor?channel=1&subtype=1 "   -f hls    -hls_flags delete_segments    -hls_time 5  -segment_time 5 -hls_list_size 5 C:\Apache24\htdocs\ipcam\video_1\stream.m3u8